# Segmentation fault while creating a list

Tags: c, list, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am creating a new struct list in which I am going to save some information about a series of cars. I get no problems compiling the code, however as soon as I run it I get a segmentation fault.

Here is the bit of code that is the problem:

```
car* insertNode(car *head){
    car *temp;
    car *prec;
    temp=(car *)malloc(sizeof(car));
    
    if(temp!=NULL){
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL)
            head=temp;
        else{//Raggiungi il termine della lista
            for(prec=head;prec->next!=NULL;prec=prec->next);
            prec->next=temp;
        }
        getData(temp);
        printf("Inserire l'anno di immatricolazione dell'auto: ");
        scanf("%i",&temp->anno);
    }
    else
        printf("Memoria esaurita!\n");
    
    return head;
}
```

I tried debugging this and I founf out that the problem lays in the line of code that has the for loop. What's the problem? I am using just <stdio.h> and <stdlib.h> libraries and I can't use other libraries for this work, but I don't get what's the problem.

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem. The code you are showing us is the *victim* and the bug is in the perpetrator, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: @Il_Kevo Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by reading your code, it seems to be correct; if it generates a segmentation falut error, I think the only way is because "head" maybe not properly initialized to null.

Additionally, debugging empty loops maybe difficult. Consider (just for debugging purposes) to add some dummy statement inside the loop (i.e. incrementing a counter).

You should also use the memory view (if possible in your debugger) to check the contents of memory locations where pointers are pointing to.

Good luck!

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I agree, Vlad, but my current reputation does not allow me to comment on third party posts, only on own posts. So, it is the only way I found to give a hint to this user. Please, let me know if I can use a different method, I'm not so used to all the functionalities and policies in the forum.